# CSS3-анимация SVG-изображения

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation

Мне нужно сделать первую точку моего `bubble chat` периодически видимой и невидимой в цикле - `infinit CSS3 animation`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему мой код не работает?

```css
@keyframes onoff {
  0% { display: none; }
  25% { display: block; }
  50% { display: none; }
  100% { display: block; }
}
#circle1 {
  animation: onoff 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <g stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none">
    <path d="M.5 16.5c0 .553.447 1 1 1h2v4l4-4h15c.552 0 1-.447 1-1v-13c0-.553-.448-1-1-1h-21c-.553 0-1 .447-1 1v13z" />


    <!--Annimation on this cicle-->

    <circle id="circle1" cx="8.5" cy="10" r=".5" />

    <!-- -->

    <circle id="circle2" cx="16.5" cy="10" r=".5" />
    <circle id="circle3 " cx="12.5" cy="10" r=".5" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Перевод вопроса: [SVG image CSS3 animation @Chloe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33128730/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128730/svg-image-css3-animation/33128938#33128938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример на css

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.bubble-chat{
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-bottom: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.bubble-chat:before,
.bubble-chat:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
.bubble-chat:before{
   left: 0;
   width: 20px;  
}
.bubble-chat:after{
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;  
}
.bubble-chat-arrow,
.bubble-chat-arrow:after{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.bubble-chat-arrow{
  top: calc(100% - 10px); left: 20px; 
  height: 50px;    
}
.bubble-chat-arrow:after{
  content: '';
  bottom: -10px; right: -22px;  
  height: 68px;    
  transform: rotate(49deg);
}
.bubble-chat-circle,
.bubble-chat-circle:before,
.bubble-chat-circle:after{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.bubble-chat-circle{
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;  
}
.bubble-chat-circle:before{
  content: ''; 
  left: -50px;
  animation: animChatOff 2s infinite;
}
.bubble-chat-circle:after{
  content: '';    
  right: -50px;
}
@keyframes animChatOff {
  0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  50%      { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-chat">
  <span class="bubble-chat-arrow"></span>
  <span class="bubble-chat-circle"></span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Свойство `display` не является анимационным ([см. MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Summary))  Тем не менее, вы можете анимировать [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Summary)

Пример:

```css
@keyframes onoff {
  0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  50%      { opacity: 1; }
}
#circle1 {
  animation: onoff 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <g stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none">
    <path d="M.5 16.5c0 .553.447 1 1 1h2v4l4-4h15c.552 0 1-.447 1-1v-13c0-.553-.448-1-1-1h-21c-.553 0-1 .447-1 1v13z" />
    <circle id="circle1" cx="8.5" cy="10" r=".5" />
    <circle id="circle2" cx="16.5" cy="10" r=".5" />
    <circle id="circle3 " cx="12.5" cy="10" r=".5" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [SVG image CSS3 animation @web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33128938/7394871)